# Make one mandatory field when the other is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with setting up a loop that would set one item as mandatory when the second one is empty, and when we fill the second one, the first one ceases to be mandatory.

When, for example, I did so like before, its do it nothing ?  What will be the best way to resolve this

This is my source code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/awx07mgv/4/

JS parts of code:

```
gadget.functions.MandatorySingelManagementBA_MX_Credit_Management=function(){
   var resgistration_number = thisPointer.entity.getValue('resgistration_number');
   var vat_id = thisPointer.entity.getValue('vat_id');
   if(resgistration_number != ''){
       jQ('[id="vat_id"]').prop('required',false);
       jQ('[id="resgistration_number"]').prop('required',true);
   }else if(vat_id != ''){
       jQ('[id="resgistration_number"]').prop('required',false);
       jQ('[id="vat_id"]').prop('required',true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle says `gadget is not defined`.

Comment: @RyanWilsonyes yes, but i put this i this on beginning page on my JS , but how my code looks ok ?